# Как восстановить удалённую папку /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, x86-64, recovery

Когда я пытался очистить систему (удаляя ненужные файлы и папки) случилось ужасное событие:  Я случайно удалил системную папку **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu**. Система крашнулась, и теперь когда я выбираю Ubuntu в GRUB Menu - я получаю ошибку (Подробней на изображении), так что я теперь не могу получить доступ к совему Ubuntu.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас я запускаю Ubuntu через загрузочный USB накопитель. Что если я скопирую папку **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu** с моей Ubuntu на USB в ту которая находится на накопителе? Решит ли это проблему? Если оно не поможет, то как исправить проблему?

Я начинающий пользователь Ubuntu, так что я буду рад если вы опишите решению проблемы просто и шаг за шагом, чтобы я смог понять :)

В любом случае, спасибо за любые ответы! :)

Comment: Uliza swali lako kwa Kirusi.

Comment: для новичка выход один: переустановить систему. p.s. я думаю, даже переводить вопрос на русский не стоит.

Comment: А копирование этой папки из загрузочной флешки на упавшую Ubuntu не поможет?((

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1209900/178576)

Comment: Копирование этой папки создаст проблем с обновлением

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я ожидал, всё что мне нужно было сделать это скопировать **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu** папку из Ubuntu находящуюся в флеш накопителе в крашнутую Ubuntu.

Больше деталей того что я сделал после того как система крашнулась:

1. Создайте загрузочный накопитель(к примеру флешку) и запуститесь от неё (нажмите F9 когда компьютер включается, в меню выберите: boot from USB-dick).
2. Скопируйте папку в старую Ubuntu, и напишите такую команду:

```bsh
sudo cp -R usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

3. Перезапустите компьютер, запуститесь под старой Ubuntu (нажмите F9 когда переключаетесь в компьютере, в меню выберите: boot from Ubuntu)
4. Проблема решена! Нет больше *тёмных*  окон с непонятными ошибками!

Comment: Проблемы будут)