# Как восстановить случайно удаленную папку */usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu*?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, recovery

Всем привет!

Стало заканчиваться место на диске, и я решил попробовать почистить систему от "ненужных" файлов. Не знаю, зачем я полез чистить что-то в системных файлах, однако под горячую руку мне попалась увесистая папка /usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu. Недолго думая, я смело ее снес, и через 5-7 минут вся система упала со следующим сообщением(см. фото) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Насколько я понял, Ubuntu закономерно не может найти файл, находящийся в папке, которая была удалена.
На картинке не очень хорошо виден текст, так что дублирую:
*/sbin/init: error while loading shared libraries: libseccomp.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

Я долго не мог понять, что послужило причиной проблемы, потому что было удалено немало всего, и спустя день безуспешных попыток восстановить систему, я запустился с загрузочной флешки, обнаружив в системных файлах ту же самую папку, и подумал - может  взять и скопировать ее в старую Ubuntu. Решит ли это проблему?

Я новичок в Ubuntu, и пока что не очень понимаю как тут все работает, и в последнем предложении возможно сказал чепуху - не судите строго)

Как решить данную проблему, и работает ли предложенный выше метод?

Заранее спасибо всем, кто ответит! Пригодится любой совет! :)

Comment: Вы по сути снесли всю систему, так что только переустановка

Comment: Если руки чешутся, можно попробовать скопировать туда минимально необходимые файлы и через LiveCD/LiveUSB через chroot переустановить все установленные пакеты чтобы скачались недостающие файлы, но это не точно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за ответы, но я справился с проблемой следующим путем: как я и предполагал, все, что мне нужно было сделать - это скопировать удаленную папку /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu с загрузочной флешки Ununtu на упавшую Ubuntu.

Подробнее о том, что нужно было сделать после сбоя системы:

1. Создать загрузочную флешку, загрузиться с нее (нажать F9 при включении компьютера, в меню выбрать - загрузиться с USB-диска).
2. Скопировать нужную нам папку на старом Ubuntu, сделать это можно командой: sudo cp -R usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.
3. Перезагрузить компьютер, запуститься под старой Ubuntu (нажать F9 при включении компьютера, в меню выбрать - загрузиться с Ubuntu) - проблема решена: больше никаких черных окон с непонятными ошибками. :)

Возможно это решение проблемы подойдет не всем, но у меня сработало!

Comment: А пакеты, которые не были установлены на старом Ubuntu, починить забыли.

Comment: Действительно, забыл, и возникли проблемы с компиляцией С-файлов, такие как: error while loading shared libraries: libbfd-2.34-system.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. Решил я эту проблему еще раз переустановив папку, только в этот раз не из сырой убунты, а из сторонней убунты той же давности, что и моя. Возможно, в дальнейшем опять вылезут какие-то проблемы, но на данный момент никаких неисправностей я пока что не обнаружил)